# How to calculate mean over comma separated column with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider the following CSV file `test.csv`:

```
"x","y","A","B"
8000000000,"0,1","0.113948,0.113689",0.114042
8000000000,"0,1","0.114063,0.113823",0.114175
8000000000,"0,1","0.114405,0.114366",0.114524
8000000000,"0,1,2,3","0.167543,0.172369,0.419197,0.427285",0.427576
8000000000,"0,1,2,3","0.167784,0.172145,0.418624,0.426492",0.428736
8000000000,"0,1,2,3","0.168121,0.172729,0.419768,0.427467",0.428578
```

My goal is to group the lines by the columns `"x"` and `"y"`, and compute the arithmetic mean over the columns `"A"` and `"B"`.

My first approach was to use a combination of `groupby()` and `mean()` in Pandas:

```
import pandas

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = pandas.read_csv("test.csv", header=0)
    data = data.groupby(["x", "y"], as_index=False).mean()
    print(data)
```

Running this script yields the following output:

```
            x        y         B
0  8000000000      0,1  0.114247
1  8000000000  0,1,2,3  0.428297
```

As we can see, achieving my goal for the single-valued column `"B"` is straightforward. However, the column `"A"` is omitted. Instead, I'd like to have the column `"A"` with with a string containing the arithmetic mean for each comma-separated value. The desired output should look like this:

```
            x        y                                    A         B
0  8000000000      0,1                    0.114139,0.113959  0.114247
1  8000000000  0,1,2,3  0.167816,0.172414,0.419196,0.427081  0.428297
```

**Does anybody know how to do this?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a custom aggregate function that parses those strings into lists, finds the averages per column, and formats them back as strings:

```py
def string_mean(rows):
    data_list = []
    for row in rows:
        data_list.append([float(item) for item in row.split(",")])
    data = np.array(data_list)
    return ",".join([f"{item:.6f}" for item in data.mean(axis=0)])
    
df.groupby(["x", "y"], as_index=False).agg({"A": string_mean, "B": "mean"})
```

which returns

```
            x        y                                    A         B
0  8000000000      0,1                    0.114139,0.113959  0.114247
1  8000000000  0,1,2,3  0.167816,0.172414,0.419196,0.427081  0.428297
```

Note it will error if your strings in A have a different number of columns in a single group.

You can probably clean up my function above considerably btw